# log4net: udp appender to splunk only logs first character

Tags: .net-core, log4net, splunk

I have a simple application which should forward all logs to a splunk server. For this I use log4net with the udp appender.

The problem is only the first character seems logged in splunk:

[image: Splunk]
Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjehC.jpg

I traced the request with wireshark:

```
¬)yElb!
J
ÿ-X,Ñ[date=2019-05-27 15:00:27,489] [level=INFO ] [environment=xxx] [hostname=xxx] [type=web] [logger=SplunkLogger] [message=Working on 634726506325099884]
```

There is another tool we use that is using log4net too and this one works without problems. Sadly I have no access to the source. So I think the splunk server is configured correctly.

log4net.conf

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<log4net>

  <root>
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="SplunkAppender" />
    <appender-ref ref="FileAppender" />
  </root>

  <logger name="SecurityLogging">
    <level value="ERROR" />
  </logger>



    <appender name="SplunkAppender" type="log4net.Appender.UdpAppender">
      <threshold value="INFO" />
      <remoteAddress value="xxxx" />
      <remotePort value="xxxx" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="[date=%date] [level=%-5level] [environment=xxxx] [hostname=%property{log4net:HostName}] [type=web] [logger=%logger] [message=%message]" />
      </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
      <file value="log-file.txt" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="[date=%date] [level=%-5level] [environment=xxxx] [hostname=%property{log4net:HostName}] [type=web] [logger=%logger] [message=%message]" />
      </layout>
    </appender>

</log4net>
```

Comment: It seems related to .NET core. Here you can see that the requests are different: https://imgur.com/YhXzLgK (right, classic .net and left .net core)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After finding out, that the sent udp request was different between .net and .net core, I had the assumption that maybe the encoding seems to be the problem.

Adding

```
<encoding value="utf-8" />
```

to the appender section did solve the problem.